# Name of Docker Image changes after hitting Enter when trying to run on VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, archlinux

I just noticed the weirdest thing ever.

I built my docker image and called it `rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest`. This is my output of `docker images`

[image]

My docker image is based on Ubuntu 16.04 (Yeah, I know it's losing support this year. I gotta update it)

I tried to run the image into a container with the following command.

```
docker run -it --name=encee-flask -p 81:5000 -d -v ~/Documents/Encee\ Outputs/:/home/Encee\ Outputs/ rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest
```

When I ran it, this is what came up.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see that each time I try to run the command and hit enter, some discrepancy occurs in the name of the image, which docker can't find locally (obviously) and hence, tries to pull from dockerhub each time. At first, I thought this could be due to the **Insert** key being activated. But upon further experimentation, the Insert key did not prove to be a factor here.

**My OS**

I use [Garuda Linux](https://garudalinux.org/) which is a distribution based on Arch Linux.

[image]

**VS Code Version - ([code](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/) - open source AUR release)**

[image]

**VS Code Colour Theme** - Cyberpunk

Comment: you know when you use the docker run you are creating a container each time. You should give it a name then you can start/stop the name and keep it to a single container.

Comment: @RobertSaylor Yes yes I do know that. But, the container isn't even being created. It can't even find the image I created locally. So that doesn't explain the typo that occurs there.

Comment: so if you list the images via command line do you see your image? # docker image ls

Comment: Yeah. There is a picture of that in this post. Please do upvote this question so we can get a better reach. I want to fix this ASAP, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe try to use a shell without PS1 customatisation, and in a clean terminal (do the `reset` command). A few times I had display problems due to escape codes leftovers.

Comment: @gileri I did that. It seems to work fine now. But I did experience this problem once again, before it then disappeared without a trace.

Comment: I guess this is because of the shell - fish. Check it out with bash.